# PYTHON: Rename Blender Windows

Tags: python

I have a specific question. If it's possible to get all Blender windows and rename them with **Python**? Any OS Platform.
For example, I would like to rename windows **"Blender"** to **"MyBlender"**.

Comment: It's not possible to directly rename the application windows from within Python. The names of the application windows are managed by the operating system's window manager and are not exposed through Blender's Python API.